# Distributing GUI Applications Written in Cython on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, cython

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I've been searching all day for an answer but I just can't find one. I'm creating a gui application using Cython on Mac OS X using PySide. I have chosen to use Cython because of speed concerns. I suppose a little side-question would be, am I creating a fuss over nothing, do I even need to worry about speed?

I have heard that the Cython compiler creates .c files. However, I can't distribute those as my application (obviously). I would like to distribute it as an application bundle (.app), rather than just an executable.

I have tried compiling c code using Xcode, but it creates a Unix Executable File, which, when run, opens a terminal window, which is not acceptable, seeing as my application has its own gui.

I have also looked at the Apple documentation about bundles, and I could create one manually if need be, but I would prefer to have the bundle created by xcode (or some other program), so there's less messing up involved.

***Edit:***
I would not get the *full* speed benefit from Cython, but I believe I would get most of it. Would it work to compile my Cython code into a python package (in the .so format), then access it from a python application packaged with py2app, which all it did was import the library and start the gui? It's just a little workaround I thought of, so feel free to tell me if its foolish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it work to compile my Cython code into a python package (in the
>   .so format), then access it from a python application packaged with
>   py2app, which all it did was import the library and start the gui?

That is what Cython does. It first generates optimized `.c` and `.h` files and then compile them into a python package as a shared object `.so` file. So the answer should be Yes. Actually, once compiled, the `.so` is independent of the generated source files and should be available for being dynamically loaded by any third party application that embeds a Python interpreter. Py2app should be OK with that. At least I suppose so...

For the rest, I don't know much about Xcode.

Edit : May be have a look at `--use-pythonpath` and/or `--frameworks` py2app's options.

Comment: That will still have a good speed bonus right? I presume it will, because the python interpreter has to read a lot less python code.

Comment: The more C code you have, the faster it will be. Read the basics of Cython: The first well known improvement is that you'll save a lot by typing explicitly - `cdef keyword`. For example, when incrementing  in [for loops](http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.fr/2011/06/speeding-up-python-numpy-cython-and.html). As well as [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/early_binding_for_speed.html), [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html), also [this](http://blog.perrygeo.net/2008/04/19/a-quick-cython-introduction/).